# Sum on vba script from another table

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, count

I have to create a vba script that takes data from a column of another table in Excel (`"Days Of Last Update"`, which is decimal), and then makes a sum based if the day are above 2 (showing the result in a new column).
It seems to be very simple, but I am a beginner and have no idea how to proceed.

---

UPDATE:

Hello everyone, thanks for the help. Now I have a new problem, still in this project. Here is what I've done:

- The RawData's sheet have a column named `"Days Since Last Update"`, that tells me when the Service Request of the product is updated. So, I created a new column with *this* formula `=IF(N:N>2,1,0)`, to tells me if the Days Since Last Updated are above 2. I refreshed my pivot table to get this new column, did a Sum of the data, and get what I previously wanted, but, when the Update function of the worksheet run, the new column of the pivot table, as well as the column of the RawData with the formula, are gone. In the code (that isn't done by me) of the Update function, there was something like this:

  Worksheets("Pivot table").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

  It has something to do with my problem?

Comment: Can you add details on your question like how your data is organized. What are you counting? If you could post as simple sample data and your expected result, that would be awesome. Right now, I can't give you even a hint on how to proceed due to minimal information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please find the sample data sheet appended below.
   [image: count on macro from another table]
2. VBA Code is appended below.

   ```
     Sub Extract_Values()

           Dim wks As Worksheet
           Dim startRow As Integer
           Dim lastRow As Integer
           Dim vArray As Variant
           Dim vNewArray As Variant
           Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
           Dim Counter1 As Integer, Counter2 As Integer

           startRow = 2
           Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")

           With wks
           lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
           vArray = .Range("A" & startRow & ":D" & lastRow).Value2
           For i = 1 To UBound(vArray)
             If vArray(i, 4) = "Y" Then
             Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
           End If
           Next i
          ReDim vNewArray(1 To Counter1, 1 To 2)
         For j = 1 To UBound(vArray)
         If vArray(j, 4) = "Y" Then
        Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
        vNewArray(Counter2, 1) = vArray(j, 1)
        vNewArray(Counter2, 2) = vArray(j, 2)
        End If
        Next
       End With

       Range("E" & startRow & ":F" & startRow + Counter1 - 1) = vNewArray
       Range("E" & startRow & ":E" & startRow + Counter1 - 1).Select
       Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
       Range("F" & startRow + Counter1).Select
       End Sub
   ```
3. I am also a beginner setting proper VBA code in cell F8 which I have calculated Excel in-built Count Function.
4. COLUMN D Contains IF Formula like 'D2=IF(B2>1,"Y","N")'
   HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim NewRow As Integer

RowCount = 2
NewRow = 2

Do Until RowCount > Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    If Cells(RowCount, 2) > 1 Then
        Range(Cells(NewRow, 5), Cells(NewRow, 6)).Value = Range(Cells(RowCount, 1), Cells(RowCount, 2)).Value
        NewRow = NewRow + 1
    End If

    RowCount = RowCount + 1
Loop
```

End Sub